# How to retrieve photo extension (jpg/png) in iOS 8.0 using Photos API?

Tags: ios8, photos, photosframework

Am trying to get file extension of photos using the new Photos API in iOS 8 but haven't found a way to do so until now. Before iOS 8.0 I would use ALAssetRepresentation to get the file extension like:

```
// Get asset representation from asset
ALAssetRepresentation *assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];

// Extract file extension from the original file name
NSString* fileExt = [[assetRepresentation filename] pathExtension];
```

Is there any way to get file extension of photos now? 
PS: I am using new Photos API as I need to access all photos in my photos app, and ALassetsLibrary gives access to "Recently Added" photos only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've got it.

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:imageRequestOptions resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {

        NSLog(@"info - %@", info);
    }];

PHImageFileDataKey = <PLXPCShMemData: 0x179ab6d0> bufferLength=1384448 dataLength=1384448;
PHImageFileOrientationKey = 1;
PHImageFileSandboxExtensionTokenKey = "c05e608acaf0bb212086ed2d512ccc97ea720ac3;00000000;00000000;0000001a;com.apple.app-sandbox.read;00000001;01000003;0000000000030b8c;/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/102APPLE/IMG_2607.JPG";
PHImageFileURLKey = "file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/102APPLE/IMG_2607.JPG";
PHImageFileUTIKey = "public.jpeg";
PHImageResultDeliveredImageFormatKey = 9999;
PHImageResultIsDegradedKey = 0;
PHImageResultIsInCloudKey = 0;
PHImageResultIsPlaceholderKey = 0;
PHImageResultWantedImageFormatKey = 9999;
```

Comment: Do you know how can we get the same for videos or audios?

Comment: may be check -requestPlayerItemForVideo method

Comment: @GarimaSrivastava You can actually use the same method to get info for a video, it just does not pass back all of the same objects!

Comment: @alex not all of the above keys are documented or present in the public API. I'm just weary that using them now may break them in the future if Apple decides or remove or rename them.

Comment: This call requires network access to determine the UTI for items in the cloud. Is there any way around that? It seems like the Photos framework doesn't know what format an image in the cloud is until it downloads and that's rather sub-optimal if you want to just get the GIFs from the library!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
PHImageRequestOptions * imageRequestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
imageRequestOptions.synchronous = YES;

[[PHImageManager defaultManager]
 requestImageForAsset:asset
 targetSize:CGSizeMake(2048, 2048)
 contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit
 options:imageRequestOptions
 resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
 }];
```

The file name is contained in info. For example:

```
PHImageFileURLKey = "file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0066.JPG";
```

Comment: There is no such a key in info. Here they are:   PHImageFileOrientationKey = 0;
    PHImageResultDeliveredImageFormatKey = 4031;
    PHImageResultIsDegradedKey = 0;
    PHImageResultWantedImageFormatKey = 4031;

Comment: This is a valid answer. Try use original size or maximum size for targetSize.

Comment: This call requires network access to determine the UTI for items in the cloud. Is there any way around that? It seems like the Photos framework doesn't know what format an image in the cloud is until it downloads and that's rather sub-optimal if you want to just get the GIFs from the library!

Comment: For video using the PHImageFileURLKey gives incorrect filename for the movie asset and tags on a .jpg at the end instead of say .MOV

Using requestAVAssetForVideo return the correct filename but it's embedded in the PHImageFileSandboxExtensionTokenKey and looks like
 "f24525397a8e061d41adb973502e7574eaf07390;00000000;00000000;000000000000001b;com.apple.avasset.read-only;00000001;01000004;0000000000fdce91;/users/username/library/developer/coresimulator/devices/7630c944-177a-4899-b5ac-7a52f30b0fff/data/media/dcim/100apple/img_0006.mov". 

Not as easy to extract

Answer (score 0):

**imageManager.requestImageDataForAsset((images[indexPath.row] as PHAsset), options:PHImageRequestOptions(), resultHandler: {imagedata,dataUTI,Orientation,info in

var str:String=((((info as Dictionary)["PHImageFileURLKey"])! as NSURL).lastPathComponent as String)
cell.imageName.text=str as String**

Answer (score 0):

These is also once simple way to get original file name selected from photos

```
PHAsset *asset; // Init this object with your PHAsset object 

//and then use below line 
NSLog(@"asset ext : %@",[[asset valueForKey:@"filename"] pathExtension]);
```