# Get File Extension from a PHAsset in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

Is there any way to distinguish a PHAsset's file extension?  My app needs to know if the photo is a .GIF or not.  I'm not seeing any way to do this.

Comment: Check please my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919512/how-to-retrieve-photo-extension-jpg-png-in-ios-8-0-using-photos-api/26011996#26011996

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File names are an implementation detail, and may or may not tell you what the content of a file really is.

When you call [`requestImageDataForAsset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHImageManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PHImageManager/requestImageDataForAsset:options:resultHandler:), the `dataUTI` parameter that Photos passes to your completion handler tells you the Uniform Type Identifier for the image data.

Comment: This call requires network access to determine the UTI for items in the cloud. Is there any way around that? It seems like the Photos framework doesn't know what format an image in the cloud is until it downloads and that's rather sub-optimal if you want to just get the GIFs from the library!

Answer (score 10):

A better approach would be to use uniformTypeIdentifier. Files can be named anything and may or may not contain a file extension.

```
[asset valueForKey:@"uniformTypeIdentifier"];
```

Comment: Is it private API?

Answer (score 6):

Using valueForKey: you can get the PHAsset file name from that you extract file extension using "pathExtension"
For Example:
PHAsset *selectedAsset = ...

```
NSString *fileName =[selectedAsset valueForKey:@"filename"];
NSString * fileExtension = [fileName pathExtension];
```

Answer (score 2):

`PHAssetResource.uniformTypeIdentifier` seems to do the job.
`PHAsset`s can be fetched by using the class function `PHAssetResource. assetResources(for:)`.

An image does **NOT** mean only there will be only one item in the list, so check out the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 Elegant Solution

```
extension PHAsset {
    func getFileName() -> String? {
        return self.value(forKey: "filename") as? String
    }

    func getExtension() -> String? {
        guard let fileName = self.getFileName() else {
            return nil
        }
        return URL(fileURLWithPath: fileName).pathExtension
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, Use:

```
URL(fileURLWithPath: (asset.value(forKey: "filename") as! String)).pathExtension
```